# MapServer WFS Filter incorrectly maps PropertyName as Literal instead of MySQL Field

Tags: wfs, mapserver, mysql

I've never used MapServer before, but have been tasked with migrating a legacy website which uses it to an updated server, including an upgrade to MapServer 7.6.2. Most stuff just works, but I'm having issues with MySQL layers and mapping of the WFS Filter PropertyName.

The layer is defined as follows

```
CONNECTION     'mysql:xxx_db,user=yyy,password=zzz,port=3306,tables=cor_tbl_spatial'
DATA           'SELECT item,geometry,geomtype FROM cor_tbl_spatial'
```

An example WFS Filter in the query is:

```
FILTER=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>item</PropertyName><Literal>A1</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>
```

MapServer logging reports the generated SQL as:

```
msOGRFileWhichShapes: SQL = SELECT id,geometry,geomtype FROM cor_tbl_spatial WHERE ((CAST("item" AS CHARACTER(4096)) = 'A1'))
```

This obviously fails as item is a field name and not a literal string. It used to work in the old server, and works fine when using GML layers. Is this a bug in MapServer, or an undocumented change in behaviour? Or is there some way to tell MapServer that these are fields not literals?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in `WHERE ((CAST("id" AS CHARACTER(4096)) = 'A1'))`. In SQL `"id"` within double quotes means the field or "identifier". Test with simplified query with some SQL client `select cast("id" as character(4096)) from "cor_table_spatial"`. But it seems that MySQL does not follow the standard https://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-035.html if not run in the ANSI mode https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html that sets it to "to conform more closely to standard SQL".

Comment: technically I don't think you can use `id` as a property name - so `id in ('A1')` would be better.

Comment: The id was a simplification of the SQL from the actual field names used, I'll edit to use something else generic.

Comment: @user It may well be MySQL specific, I obviously tested that WHERE "item" = 'A1' returns 0 results but WHERE item = 'A1' returns 2 results. Which makes it even more likely a Mapserver or OGR bug. Who even runs in ANSI these days?

Comment: Databases like PostgreSQL, Oracle etc. follow the SQL standard that is often called ANSI standard but actually seems to be an ISO standard https://blog.ansi.org/2018/10/sql-standard-iso-iec-9075-2016-ansi-x3-135/. Even MySQL tries to do that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/differences-from-ansi.html. The GDAL driver has one test in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_mysql.py that suggests that GDAL knows the MySQL way `gdaltest.mysql_ds.ExecuteSQL("DROP TABLE 'select'")`. Maybe the bug is in MapServer. As far as I know not so many MapServer users run MySQL.

Comment: Yeah, apologies @user30184 for my confusion, I was thinking ANSI charset rather than ANSI SQL... Definitely looks to be the ANSI mode setting, but I'm reluctant to change that on the server as we have other sites running there. Will need some thought. I'm digging in both code bases to try decipher where it happens, I'd agree probably Mapserver as I assume it's the one translating WFS filters into MySQL queries and not OGR which is probably just running the computed query.

Comment: Looks to be https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/blob/c046f6b4aabcf2f99ae17a86d449461b412142d0/mapogr.cpp#L3656

Comment: Bug report https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/issues/6612. Thanks for your help @user30184 !

Comment: There were several major security concerns fixed in 7.6.3 (and yesterday's 8.0.0) release of MapServer, I strongly suggest you upgrade to either 7.6.4 or preferably 8.0.0.  More on yesterday's big 8.0 release: https://mapserver.org/development/announce/8-0.html